# Как обойти ошибку получения файла october cms System\Models\File?

Tags: php, laravel, плагин, octobercms

Использую следующий код

```
if($file->fromUrl($url)) // место ошибки
{
    $post->featured_images()->save($file);
}
```

Ошибка:

```
In File.php line 175:
Error getting file "тут урл картинки", error code: 400
```

Как мне обработать эту ошибку или просто пропустить, чтобы скрипт дальше продолжал работать?

Comment: обернуть эту часть в try ... catch

Comment: да, я уже пробовал, но почему-то не работало. Нужно было добавить слэш перед исключением: catch (\Exception $ex)

Comment: `да, я уже пробовал, но почему-то не работало`. А вам ошибка должна была упасть, что класс Exception не найден. Всегда смотрите ошибки. Если ошибки не выводятся - научитесь  включать их показ. Ну и поменяйте Exception на `\Throwable` как более универсальный и расширенный. [мана](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    $file->fromUrl($url);
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    //handle exception here
}
```